# How to post a tweet with Meteor.js, Twitter and Oauth

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, meteor

i have a little problem with Meteor and Twitter.
All i want to do is posting a tweet through a click on a button. For this I have to authenticate myself over Oauth to the Twitterservice.

At the moment i am doing the authentification in a really complicated way springing from client to server and back. But now I found the function Meteor.loginWithTwitter. Originally I thought this function is only for logging you into your own application with the Twitterkeys, now i am not so sure anymore. Probably I can also use it for my problem. Because it seems that the Oauth-Process is completely (and in a simple way) implemented in Meteor.

Sadly i cann't find any documentation or examples for just logging in and getting the final oauth_token. And so all i got from Meteor back then i try the following code, is this errormessage:

Erromessage: Accounts.ConfigError {message: "Service not configured"}

```
Meteor.loginWithTwitter( function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    console.log("yeah");
 }
});
```

I know i have to enter somewhere my Appinformation like the Consumer key, but i have no idea where. Can someone help me out and knows some examples for me? Or knows if i am even on the right track?

Thanks and greetings 
Philipp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this: Add the accounts-ui package:

```
meteor add accounts-ui accounts-twitter
```

and in your template do

```
{{loginButtons}}
```

On the first start of the application, a click on the login button will guide you through the setup process. You will create a Twitter application and copy the consumer key and consumer secret into a form, that meteor presents you. Afterwards you can log in using Twitter.

Make sure to use the latest Meteor version (0.5.2 at this moment)

Comment: this answer is outdated now  it should be `{{>loginButtons}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also config your consumer key and secret with code, this is an example with weibo but its work for twitter, google etc... (server side) :

```
// first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "weibo"
});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "weibo",
    clientId: "1292962797",
    secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add what @Tom31 suggested **in your server side**, i.e., I have a /server/server.js

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({"service": "twitter"});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
 "service": "twitter",
 "consumerKey" : "<yours>",
 "secret" : "<yours>"
});
```

Finally, your access token are stored in your user at the database but this information it is not propagated to the client and, if you want to have access to it, you new to create a server side method and access it through [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) or [Meteor.apply](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_apply)

**Updated: Example of my server side method**

I've created my server side method like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
...
  userGet: function(id) {
   return removeSensibleFields( Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: id }) );
  }
...
});
```

where **removeSensibleFields** is a method to remove all unnecessary/private information that may not be sent back to the client

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the server side method would look like?